# How to write query in Ruby to check certain time object is less than 1 hour or 3 hour

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a **Trip** model in ruby which has **start_at** column and i need to get **Trip** object if **start_at** less than 1 hour or 3 hour (only i should get trip object when **start_at** is < 1hr or < 3hr not for < 2hr, < 4hr, ..... etc).

Note: I have **Cron** job which runs for every 15.minutes to get **trip** object as explained above.

Example: Assume i have a trip which start_at = 9:00 am and current time is 10:00 am i should get that trip object. Same goes for 3 hour also (start_at = 9:00 am and current time is 12:00 am)

^^ Except above two cases i should not get trip object, need to get only for less than 1hr or 3hr

**This is what i tried**

```
Trip.where("start_at < ? ", 1.hour.ago)
```

But above query returning trip object even if start_at < 2 hours ago, 4 hours ago, ..... blah blah

I am new to Ruby any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```rb
Trip.where(start_at: 2.hours.ago..1.hour.ago).or(Trip.where(start_at: 4.hours.ago..3.hour.ago))
```

Comment: Personally I would flip this so that its `1.hour.ago..2.hours.ago`.

Comment: I just use `from` `lower` `to` `higher`,  I think it will be easy to understand

Answer (score -1):

You could use [or](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/or) query, or use array value:

```rb
Trip.where(start_at: [2.hours.ago..1.hour.ago, 4.hours.ago..3.hour.ago])
```